# What is the pandas equivalent of sort foo | uniq -c (and how to label the count column as 'Count')?

Tags: python, pandas

Having spent many hours trying to solve this, I have managed to get close to an answer, but not exactly there. I haven't found an example that does exactly what I want, yet it seems to be a very simple thing to do.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ["A", "B", "C", "A"],
                   'ID': [1, 2, 3, 1]})
    
print("\ndf")
print(df)
```

emits

```
  Name  ID
0    A   1
1    B   2
2    C   3
3    A   1
```

What can I do to get this output?

```
 Name  ID Count
    A   1     2
    B   2     1
    C   3     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below answer should help you:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ["A", "B", "C", "A"],
                   'ID': [1, 2, 3, 1]})

df = df.groupby(["Name", "ID"])["Name"].count().reset_index(name="Count")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Name  ID  Count
0    A   1      2
1    B   2      1
2    C   3      1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby(['Name', 'ID']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'COUNT'})
```